# How to stub ShopifyAPI::DraftOrder get and find method in RSPEC

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, shopify, rspec-rails, shopify-app

In my **RSPEC test** I want to make a fake request in Shopify and returns static values(hash).

I'm aiming to have something like (**but I can't get to return static_hash**):

```
# find specific draft order
allow(ShopifyAPI::DraftOrder).to receive(:find).with(draft_id).and_return({static_hash})

# or

allow(ShopifyAPI::DraftOrder).to receive(:all).with(params: {page: 1, status: 'any'}).and_return({static_hash})



# get all draft orders
allow(ShopifyAPI::DraftOrder).to receive(:all).and_return({static_hash})
```

In my **Rails Controller**, I have:

```
# find specific draft order
ShopifyAPI::DraftOrder.find(params[:id])

# get all draft orders
ShopifyAPI::DraftOrder.all(params: {page: 1, status: 'any'})
```

Comment: Add complete spec and controller action definition to the question.

Comment: You're a bit vague saying `can't get to return ...`, what if you did `allow(ShopifyAPI::DraftOrder).to receive(:find).with(draft_id).and_return({static_hash}); expect(ShopifyAPI::DraftOrder.find(draft_id)).to eq {static_hash}` It should pass.